# Swift - Making a type Hashable that has instance variable of protocol type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

How to make a struct/class confirm to H.ashable/Equatable that has an instance variable of a protocol type. Let me provide an example of this:

```
protocol Filter {
  associatedtype Input
  func satisfies(input: Input) -> Bool
}

protocol FilterProcessor {
  func satisfies(input: String) -> Bool
}

struct SelectionFilter: Filter {
  let identifier: String
  let processor: FilterProcessor
  func satisfies(input: String) -> Bool {
    return processor.satisfies(input: input)
  }
}

struct ProcessorOne: FilterProcessor {
  let uuid: String
  let type: String
  func satisfies(input: String) -> Bool {
    // Some logic based on uuid and type
    return false
  }
}

struct ProcessorTwo: FilterProcessor {
  let data: Int
  func satisfies(input: String) -> Bool {
    // Some logic based on data
    return false
  }
}
```

This works fine as long as you don't need Hashable/Equatable confirmance on `SelectionFilter` but things quickly get very complicated as soon as you do, like try to make a Set of `SelectionFilter`:

```
Set([
SelectionFilter(identifier: "abc", processor: ProcessorOne(uuid: "1234", type: "size")),
SelectionFilter(identifier: "def", processor: ProcessorTwo(data: 1234))
])
```

For the above to work `SelectionFilter` needs to be Hashable. We can do that taking only `identifier` into account but that would be wrong as actual hashing/equality depends upon the processor's data also. For that `FilterProcessor` needs to be Hashable and as soon as we do that the `SelectionFilter` can't use the `FilterProcessor` directly as it is now a generic protocol.

One solution is to use a type eraser for the FilterProcessor as AnyFilterProcessor, but then this `AnyFilterProcessor` needs to confirm Hashable. How do you do that since all this AnyFilterProcessor will have is a closure that points back to the actual satisfies method.

So there are two alternatives I could make one is to make SelectionFilter an enum and the other is to eliminate the FilterProcessor and make SelectionFilter a class and other subclasses:

Option1:

```
enumm SelectionFilter: Filter, Hashable {
case filterOne(identifier: String, processor: ProcessorOne)
case filterTwo(identifier: String, processor: ProcessorTwo)
}

extension ProcessorOne: Hashable {}
extension ProcessorTwo: Hashable {}
```

This works neatly but the problem is that enums are not scalable. We have some 20 odd processors, which means 20 cases and for doing anything we need to switch all 20 cases.

Option2:

```
class SelectionFilter: Filter, Hashable {

  let identifier: String
  
  init(identifier: String) {
    self.identifier = identifier
  }

  func satisfies(input: String) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: SelFilter, rhs: SelFilter) -> Bool {
    lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
  }
  
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(identifier)
  }
}

class FilterOne: SelectionFilter {
  let uuid: String
  let type: String
  
  init(identifier: String, uuid: String, type: String) {
    self.uuid = uuid
    self.type = type
    super.init(identifier: identifier)
  }

  override func satisfies(input: String) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

But the issue here is a lot of duplicate code as each SelectionFilter subclass will need to implement `==` and `hash` functions. Also, it is error-prone as any developer might forget to implement these functions in a subclass.

Both of these options work but I am really not liking them. Is there is another way to do it?